# OAuth2RestTemplate The access token provided has expired

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I was trying to find solution for a very long time and didn't find anything useful.
Now, straight to problem.

I have to use remote OAuth2 authentication server and I have credentials for using it. Authentication is used for REST service calls.
REST service are being called in 15 minutes interval and our application calls more than one URL in one iteration.

For the first time REST API is called, everything is allright, we get access token and it's useful.
After 1 hour, when access token expires and REST API is called again, we get following error:

```
The access token provided has expired
```

This error is shown sometimes once, sometimes twice or more.
After another 15 minutes REST API call is errorless again.

I tried to use property `retryBadAccessTokens`, but with no luck.
We are using `spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE` with following settings:

```
<bean id="oipRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref="oipClientCredentialsResourceDetail"/>
    <property name="accessTokenProvider" ref="tokenProvider"/>
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
    <property name="retryBadAccessTokens" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" >
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg value="application" />
                            <constructor-arg value="json" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="errorHandler">
        <bean class="our.company.app.holders.MyResponseErrorHandler" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if they are also giving you a Refresh Token. You use those to generate tokens on behalf of the user.

By the way, if you are calling every 15 minutes, I would just get new tokens every time. You don't want to do that when you are making thousands of calls per minute.... but 15 minutes? Not biggie.

Comment: Response on OAuth2Request:´{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "very_long_token",
  "expires_in": 1250
}´

Comment: Yeah, you are not given a refresh token. Like I said, if you are making calls every 15 minutes, just get a new one. Believe me, it is not gong to hurt the server.

Comment: It seems like it's ok now. On the beggining of each iteration i remove access token from OAuth2ClientContext by `oipRestTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(null);`

Answer (score 1):

We have a fairly high traffic system, and I'm noting that the failures we get are always right around the moment in time that the token is about to expire.
Is it possible that the client looks at the token, which is about to expire, sends it to the server, and now it is expired, the server rejects it.

If this is the case, we would need some buffer space of at least the time difference between when Oauth2RestTemplate looks at its copy of the token, and the server looks at the token.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: The point is that Oauth2RestTemplate will automatically refresh the token by itself. However, it does have a small failure window. If it is being called just before the token expires, it will fail to refresh it, and it could be expired by the time it gets to the server. I hacked it slightly so that it stores the local copy of the token with the expiration reduced by a minute, and I've not had any problem with expired tokens since.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of posting a mod to Oauth2RestTemplate itself.

```
if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isExpired())
```

ought be

`if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isAboutToExpire())`

with some config value of how early to declare.